# How to attach values of each group?

Tags: r, data.table

I want to attach the values of a group together, here is the sample:

```
data<-data.table(group=c("g1","g1","g2","g2","g1"),value=c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

my desired output would be:

```
     group  value
1:    g1     125
2:    g2     34
```

Values could be treated as numbers or characters.

Comment: `data[,.(value=paste(value,collapse="")),by=group]`

Comment: Thanks!, I looked for . in the package, what exactly it does?

Comment: It can be used to substitute for `list(value=...)` - just saves a couple of characters.

Comment: I suggest starting with the new HTML vignettes [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: If a question is marked duplicate, should I delete it?

Comment: Soheil, no it's not necessary to delete.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the `data.table` solution from thelatemail, you can do this in base R:

```
aggregate(value ~ group, data, FUN = function(x) paste(x, collapse = ""))
```

Or with [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html):

```
data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(value = paste(value, collapse = ""))
```